# How to link libraries when cross compiling

Tags: c, linux, ld, pkg-config, vmware-tools

I'm cross compiling open VMWare tools. I pre-compiled glib and i'm setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable to link them.
I'm getting the following errors in the link stage.

```
libtool: link: warning: library `/u/git/extlib_vmtools/usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.la' was moved.
/bin/grep: /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.la: No such file or directory
/bin/sed: can't read /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[2]: *** [libhgfs.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/u/git/extlib_vmtools/src/open-vm-tools-11.0.0-14549434/libhgfs'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/u/git/extlib_vmtools/src/open-vm-tools-11.0.0-14549434'
```

I followed this helpful post ([DESTDIR and PREFIX of make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307465/destdir-and-prefix-of-make)) but I think i'm missing something.
I didn't set the `--prefix` for any module, since I want to use the default direcotry structure when deploying.

glib compilation (lower module):

```
./configure --host=${CROSS_COMPILE_HOST}
make
make install DESTDIR=/home/xport/
```

open-vmware-tools compilation (upper module):

```
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="/home/xport/"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/xport/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
autoreconf -i
./configure --host=${CROSS_COMPILE_HOST} --enable-lib64=no --without-kernel-modules --without-pam --disable-vgauth --without-x --without-gtk3 --without-gtk2 --without-gtkmm3 --without-gtkmm --enable-resolutionkms=no --enable-deploypkg=no
make
make install DESTDIR=/home/xport # <-- I don't even get here
```

Before I set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable, the second make failed due to missing .h files... So I know that `.pc` linkage works.
What am I missing ?
Thanks !

Comment: When you run `configure` you need to specify the *target* to build for, the host will by default to the local host system.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude - close. Use `--build`, not `--target`. `--target` is used for building the compiler for an arch. Very confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ./configure --host=${CROSS_COMPILE_HOST} ...
> ```

You need to set both `--build` and `--host` dues to an Autoconf bug. Assuming you are building for ARMv7l, something like:

```
./configure --host=$(config.guess) --build=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

---

The following looks OK to me, assuming `/home/xport/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` is valid and `/home/xport/usr/local` is the location of the `include/` and `lib/` files for the arch.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/xport/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
```

---

I'm not sure about what follows. It is also missing a `--build`. And I am used to seeing a `--sysroot` when cross-compiling:

```
./configure --host=${CROSS_COMPILE_HOST} \
    --enable-lib64=no --without-kernel-modules --without-pam --disable-vgauth \
    --without-x --without-gtk3 --without-gtk2 --without-gtkmm3 --without-gtkmm \
    --enable-resolutionkms=no --enable-deploypkg=no
```

`CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` should probably include `--sysroot`. Maybe something like:

```
./configure --host=$(config.guess) --build=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf \
    --sysroot="/home/xport/usr/local" --enable-lib64=no --without-kernel-modules ...
```

Or:

```
    CFLAGS="--sysroot=/home/xport/usr/local" \
    CXXFLAGS="--sysroot=/home/xport/usr/local" \
./configure --host=$(config.guess) --build=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf \
    --enable-lib64=no --without-kernel-modules ...
```

---

`DESTDIR` is intended for staging. This looks OK:

```
make install DESTDIR=/home/xport/
```

If you intend to run from the `/home/xport/` directory, then you should consider adding the following to `LDFLAGS`:

```
# 64-bit Fedora
-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-R,'$$ORIGIN/../lib64'
# Most others
-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-R,'$$ORIGIN/../lib'
```

So maybe something like:

```
    CFLAGS="--sysroot=/home/xport/usr/local" \
    CXXFLAGS="--sysroot=/home/xport/usr/local" \
    LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-R,'$$ORIGIN/../lib'" \
./configure --host=$(config.guess) --build=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf \
    --enable-lib64=no --without-kernel-modules ...
```

`$ORIGIN`-based runpaths is what makes staged installs with `DESTDIR` work.

The double dollar sign in `$$ORIGIN` is due to Makefiles. The double dollar sign is the way to escape the dollar sign so it passes through the makefile properly.

Also see [How to include correctly -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN linker argument in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42344932/608639)

---

`config.guess` provides you with your Autoconf triplet:

```sh
$ /usr/share/libtool/build-aux/config.guess
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

If you don't have a `config.guess` on-path, then check for it in `/usr/share`:

```sh
$ find /usr/share -name config.guess
/usr/share/misc/config.guess
/usr/share/libtool/config/config.guess
/usr/share/automake-1.14/config.guess
```

---

Also see [2.2.8 Cross-Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html) in the Autoconf manual:

> To cross-compile is to build on one platform a binary that will run on
>   another platform. When speaking of cross-compilation, it is important
>   to distinguish between the build platform on which the compilation is
>   performed, and the host platform on which the resulting executable is
>   expected to run. The following configure options are used to specify
>   each of them:
>
> --build=build
>
> The system on which the package is built.
>
> --host=host
>
> The system where built programs and libraries will run.

And a little further down:

> The --host and --build options are usually all we need for
>   cross-compiling. The only exception is if the package being built is
>   itself a cross-compiler: we need a third option to specify its target
>   architecture.
>
> --target=target
>
> When building compiler tools: the system
>   for which the tools will create output.

---

Regarding the comment *"I don't even get here"*:

> ```
> make
> make install DESTDIR=/home/xport # <-- I don't even get here
> ```

You need to show the compile error you are encountering when you run `make`.

Comment: OK Testing... config.guess=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu and CROSS_COMPILE_HOST=i686-linux. Is that OK and your comment still applies ? Because glib (one of the dependencies) fails the configure pre-check. Thanks !

Comment: Also, /home/xport is the stating directory in which I would like to exported the compilation output. I will tgz this directory and extract it in / on my target machine. So sysroot is not needed I think.

Comment: @user2491552 - Based on the `CROSS_COMPILE_HOST` comment, you should probably use `CROSS_COMPILE_HOST=i686-unknown-linux-gnu` and `--host=i686-unknown-linux-gnu` if you are building to run on 32-bit i686.

Comment: @user2491552 - Based on my experience with cross-compiling, you want to set a `--sysroot`. That is a build time option, and tells the toolchain where to find tools, headers and libraries. `--sysroot` does not affect runtime. For runtime, you want to compile and link with `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-R,'$$ORIGIN/../lib'`. That allows you to move the program around on filesystems.

Comment: @user2491552 - At this point, I think you should reboot. Use the proper triplets for `--build`, `--host` and `CROSS_COMPILE_HOST`. Set `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. Build everything again. When you have a new problem, ask a new question.