# Difficulty adding $ORIGIN to LDFLAGS

Tags: makefile, compilation, linker, configure

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344932/how-to-include-correctly-wl-rpath-origin-linker-argument-in-a-makefile), I need to pass `$ORIGIN/../lib` to my compilation procedure. I'm doing this via

```
./configure "LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,\$\$ORIGIN/../lib"
make
```

However, when I inspect the executable via `objdump -x src/foo | grep PATH`, I get

```
/home/Users/me/foo_repo/lib:/../lib
```

when what I want is

```
/home/Users/me/foo_repo/lib:$ORIGIN/../lib
```

So it looks like `$ORIGIN` is being evaluated instead of just being put into `RUNPATH`

How can I prevent this from happening? I've tried adding escapes to both `$` but get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it many times and it seems that at some point it may still be resolved to empty string, since Makefiles can be run recursively. The only way I found to be reliable was to additionally define `export ORIGIN='$ORIGIN'` in the shell where I run `configure` and `make`, so that even if shell expands `$ORIGIN` it will still result in value `$ORIGIN`.

Note also that you need also `-Wl,-z,origin` to make value `$ORIGIN` interpreted in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you need yet a third layer of quoting: because you are passing this value to the `configure` script via the command line you need to quote the value for the shell.

You run this:

```
./configure "LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,\$\$ORIGIN/../lib"
```

The shell removes the first level of quoting before invoking `configure`, so the value of `LDFLAGS` that is put into your makefile is this:

```
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,$$ORIGIN/../lib
```

Then when make runs the linker, it will convert the escaped `$$` into a single `$`, and make will invoke a shell and pass your link line with the option:

```
-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib
```

The shell will expand `$ORIGIN` because it looks like a shell variable, expand it to the empty string, and you get the result `-Wl,-rpath,/../lib`.

To get the quoting right it's often useful to work backwards.  When make invokes your link line it needs to escape the `$ORIGIN` so the shell doesn't expand it, so you want the argument to be something like:

```
'-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib'
```

In order to get that, you need your `LDFLAGS` to be set to something like:

```
LDFLAGS='-Wl,-rpath,$$ORIGIN/../lib'
```

In order to get that, you need to escape it all from the shell when you invoke configure, including the single-quotes, something like:

```
./configure "LDFLAGS='-Wl,-rpath,\$\$ORIGIN/../lib'"
```

(note, I didn't try this)

Comment: This did not work for me. The `./configure` script wouldn't even run w/ the outer quotes.

Comment: Don't know what "wouldn't even run" means.  You have to provide an error message at least.  If it literally wouldn't start then you must have a syntax error in your command line.

Comment: `gcc: error: '-Wl,-rpath,$$ORIGIN/../lib': No such file or directory` somewhere buried in the `config.log` output.

Comment: well, the problem is that the value of the LDFLAGS variable may be used by configure wen it's testing the linker, as well as make, and they have different formats.  I don't think you really need to use this option with `./configure`.  Does it work if you run configure without this `LDFLAGS` setting but then pass the `LDFLAGS` setting to `make` when you run that?

Comment: It does not, for the same reason @raspy provided in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, after several attempts, the following settings are feasible.

```bash
./configure  LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath=\\\$\$ORIGIN/../lib ${LDFLAGS}"
```