# I am trying to define a string X="either 'this|that'" but GNU make won't accept it

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a Makefile for GNU make. I can't figure out what the problem is here:

```
foo := this|works
bar := "I lost my 'single quotes'"
baz := 'make|will|not|accept|this|with|the|single|quotes'

whatIWant := "A string with its 'single|quoted|regex|alternatives'"

this-almost-works:  #But the single quotes are lost.
        @printf '%s ' "$(whatIWant)"

this-fails-horribly:
        @printf '$(whatIWant)'
```

I get the following error message

```
/bin/sh: 1: quoted: not found
/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: 1: regex: not foundalternatives": not found

blah blah Error 127
```

1. Why is it trying to run parts of this string in the shell?
2. How can I define a variable to contain exactly the contents of whatIWant?

Comment: Escape your pipes with '\', if I recall correctly pipes are special characters in makefiles

Comment: Cool. That helps avoid the error message. Though I don't really see why foo works and baz does not work. I still need those single quotes preserved. For some reason they disappear.

Comment: Make doesn't interpret quotes, they are in the string. So really what you are doing here is : 
````@printf '%s ' ""A string with its 'single|quoted|regex|alternatives'"" ```` which is interpreted with quotes so ````'single|quoted|regex|alternatives'```` loses its quotes because it is a quoted string. Does that make sense?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330243/gnu-makefile-how-to-and-when-to-quote-strings

Comment: Yes I see now. Thanks!

Comment: Pipes are _not_ special characters in makefiles, except in GNU make prerequisite lists where they separate normal prerequisites from order-only prerequisites.  They are special to the shell, but not inside quotes (of either type).

Comment: I see. What was happening was a quoting problem. Instead of sending quoted pipes to the shell, the quotes were being cancelled and the shell saw the pipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be worth looking in detail at the expansion.

When defining variables,
just about the only character that has an effect is `$`.
Everything else is taken literally.
It's worth nothing that white space around the assignment operator (`=` or `:=`) is ignored.

```
foo  :=     this|works
```

`foo` is assigned the literal text `this|works`.
Similarly,

```
baz := 'make|will|not|accept|this|with|the|single|quotes'
```

assigns the literal text `'make|will|not|accept|this|with|the|single|quotes'` to `baz`.
Fine and dandy.

Now, when *make* decides to build `this-fails-horribly`
(possibly because you said to the shell `make this-fails-horribly`)
it expands the block of commands before doing anything.
Not unreasonably,
`$(whatIWant)` is replaced by `"A string with its 'single|quoted|regex|alternatives'"`.
Again, fine and dandy.
What is left is passed verbatim, one line at a time, to the shell.
The shell sees

```
printf '"A string with its 'single|quoted|regex|alternatives'"'
```

(which *make* would have helpfully echoed to you if you had left off the `@` prefix).
Now we are in the land of shell quoting.

- The `printf` command is passed one parameter: `"A string with its single`:

  - `'"A string with its '` is a single quoted string. The shell strips the `'`s and is left with the text `"A string with its`.
  - `single` has no metacharacters in it, so the shell leaves this alone.
- The output is piped to the `quoted` command
- The output is piped to the `regex` command
- The output is piped to the `alternatives"` command

  - The shell sees the single quoted string `'='`, strips the quotes leaving you with a literal `=` which it appends to the word `alternatives`

No syntax error.
When the shell attempts to set up the pipeline it looks for the `alternatives"` command.
It doesn't find one in the directories it its `$PATH`, so it stops with the message `/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: 1: regex: not foundalternatives": not found`.

One possible encoding:

```
.PHONY: this-workes-nicely
this-workes-nicely:
    echo $(whatIWant)
```

though you'll probably find it's cleaner to leave the quotes outside the variable definition in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it all out. The whole point of the printf was for debugging purposes, so I especially appreciate the comment that the '@' was suppressing the exact message I was trying to get at.