# dependency check in automake rules

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I have some problem adding specific rules to an autotools project.

I have this small exemple project :

project/configure.ac :

```
AC_INIT([myprog], [0.1], [dev@corp.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Wall -Werror])
AM_EXTRA_RECURSIVE_TARGETS([quality])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_SUBST([AM_CFLAGS])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

project/Makefile.am:

```
SUBDIRS = src
```

project/src/Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS= myprog

myprog_SOURCES    = myprog.c

QUALITYDIR=$(builddir)/quality
QUALITY_FILE="$(QUALITYDIR)/quality.log"

quality-local: $(QUALITY_FILE)

$(QUALITY_FILE): myprog
    mkdir -p $(QUALITYDIR)
    valgrind ./myprog 2>&1 | tee $(QUALITY_FILE)

CLEANFILES =    $(QUALITY_FILE)
```

Each time I do :

$ make quality

the valgrind stuff is run, even if "myprog" has not been rebuilt.
I expect it shall only be executed when myprog is younger than the quality.log file in build/src/quality .

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into your generated `project/src/Makefile` you'll see something  like:

```
.PHONY: CTAGS GTAGS TAGS all all-am check check-am clean \
        ... quality-am quality-local ...
```

A [`.PHONY` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets) will always be remade, so yes `valgrind` will always be run (which I also observed).

EDIT:

Forget all that.  After running `make -d quality` (after already having made the log) I noticed:

```
  Considering target file '"./quality/quality.log"'.
   File '"./quality/quality.log"' does not exist.
```

So simply changing:

```
QUALITY_FILE="$(QUALITYDIR)/quality.log"
```

to

```
QUALITY_FILE=$(QUALITYDIR)/quality.log
```

should make it behave as you expect.  At least it did for me.

Comment: I don't think that explains it.  Yes, .PHONY targets are always remade, but that does not force a rebuild of their up-to-date prerequisites (consider that the conventional "all" target is ordinarily .PHONY).  The OP's valgrind command is part of the recipe for a regular target; it should run only if that rule's target is absent or out of date with respect to its prerequisites.

Comment: @JohnBollinger after playing around some more, I discovered that you are correct.

Comment: Good catch on the second try, +1.  I'll add that this sort of thing is an excellent reason to write DRY make rules, and in particular, to use the built-in variable `$@` within a rule's recipe to refer to that rule's target.

Comment: Thanks ldav1s, it works ! I don't really understand what was the problem with the double-quote though, is is a bug of automake ?

Comment: This isn't an automake bug.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332194/425738) for more information.

Comment: It isn't even directly related to Automake, @user2174468.  It is standard behavior for `make`.