# Makefile filter-out not removing a file from a list of files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm just starting out with Make and I have this file:

```
CODE_FILES := $(shell find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/[a-z_]*[a-z]\.(cpp|h)")
EXCLUDE := "./bytecode/operators.cpp"
CODE_FILES_COPY = $(filter-out $(EXCLUDE), $(CODE_FILES))

# All nested header files (.h) and source files (.cpp)

# all: a.out

a.out: main.cpp $(CODE_FILES_COPY)
    @echo $(EXCLUDE)
    @echo $(CODE_FILES_COPY)
    @echo $(CODE_FILES)
    clang++ main.cpp -o a.out -pthread -std=c++17 -g \
        -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra \
        -D DO_CACHE_DECL
# Define: -D PLUMBER_DEBUG -D DO_CACHE_DECL -D TRACKER_DEBUG 

./bytecode/operators.out: ./bytecode/operators.cpp
    clang++ ./bytecode/operators.cpp -o ./bytecode/operators.out -std=c++17 \
        -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror

make clean:
    rm -f a.out ./bytecode/operators.out
```

However, `CODE_FILES_COPY` and `CODE_FILES` are exactly the same (a long list of files containing e.g. `./foo/bar/baz.cpp`) - the `filter-out` seems to have not worked. What am I doing wrong in this situation?

I've also probably done some things wrong in the rest of the file, but the focus is on `a.out` being rebuilt if I modify `./bytecode/operators.cpp` which I don't want to happen since it takes a long time to rebuild the whole project and very little time to compile `operators.cpp`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330243/gnu-makefile-how-to-and-when-to-quote-strings/23332194#23332194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quotes around `"./bytecode/operators.cpp"` in your `EXCLUDE :=`. Remove them and your exclude will match. Your files will not have quotes around them in the list.

Try using

```
$(info CODE_FILES: $(CODE_FILES))
$(info EXCLUDE: $(EXCLUDE))
```

to see the difference