# Adding java directory to my path automatically

Tags: makefile, msys2

I'm doing this in my makefile to try and get the PATH to Java, but the resulting string from find isn't escaped properly to be used in bash, how do I get find to return the escaped path to java.exe?

```
JAVA_EXE := "$(shell find /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Java/ -type f -name 'java.exe' -print0 -quit)"
JAVA_PATH := $(dir $(JAVA_EXE))
```

Comment: You sure you need it to be escaped? You can directly write to a makefile variable named `PATH`, then do `export PATH` to turn it into an environment variable.

Comment: JAVA_EXE contains the location of the file non-escaped and usable to execute, but I need the path to the file not the file itself

Comment: I get it, but what are you planning to do with the path? Do you want to add it to the `PATH` variable?

Comment: Yes, for the path but I need two distinct variables. One to the executable and another *for adding to path*

Comment: Then my first comment applies. You might not need to escape it to add it to the `PATH`.

Comment: You are probably correct, but I definitely have to do something with it, because it contains the filename java.exe at the moment

Comment: Didn't you remove the filename using `$(dir ...)`?

Comment: I tried, but that doesn't work because the filename is invalid in bash  (i.e. contains spaces and ( and ) which are unescaped

Comment: Do not add quotes around the results of the `$(shell ...)` command.  That is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330243/gnu-makefile-how-to-and-when-to-quote-strings/23332194#23332194

Comment: The short answer is, you cannot use paths containing spaces in makefiles.  You definitely cannot use them with any make functions like `dir`, etc.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @MadScientist I don't believe that is true if I can get an escaped answer from find

Comment: `dir` is a make function.  Make has no facility for escaping whitespace.  There's no way to get the make function `$(dir ....)` to work the right way, if `...` is a path containing whitespace.

Comment: I can remove the java.exe with 

JAVA_PATH := $(subst java.exe,,$(JAVA_EXE))

This still doesn't answer my main question which is how to get  an escaped directory from find...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've learned a lot since I last posted this question.

I needed a script, like so called addJavaToPath.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_EXE=$(find "/c/Program Files" -type f -name java.exe -print -quit 2>/dev/null)
echo JAVA_EXE: $JAVA_EXE
JAVA_PATH=${JAVA_EXE%'java.exe'}
echo JAVA_PATH: $JAVA_PATH
export PATH=$PATH:"$JAVA_PATH"
```

and then you type:

```
source addJavaToPath.sh
```

it needs to be sourced because you want to mess with path and normally that export would only last for the life of the script