# Makefile docker command with single quote failling

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, makefile

With this in a Makefile:

```
single:
    docker network inspect -f '{{ .IPAM }}' web-proxy

double:
    docker network inspect -f "{{ .IPAM }}" web-proxy
```

`make single` fails with `make: docker: Permission denied` while `make double` succeeds. Both commands work if I input them directly in my bash.

It happens only since I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 (from the 22.04). I have docker 20.10.20, bash 5.1.16 and GNU Make 4.3

Any idea were it can come from ? From what I have read the Makefile doesn't care about quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332194

Comment: Just to note, the version of Ubuntu you're using is not helpful to anyone that doesn't have that version; better would be to tell us which version of GNU make you're using (run `make --version`).

Comment: Yes I should have thought of that, I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why updating your system made a difference, but this is almost certainly related to a bug in gnulib (that GNU make uses).

If you add a semicolon to the end of the `docker` command line in the `single` target I'll bet it will work again.

The bug is this: if some directory on your `PATH` contains a subdirectory with the name of a command you want to invoke, then if `make` attempts to run that command directly (without using a shell) it will fail because it tries to "run" that directory.  So for example if you have `/my/dir` in `PATH` and the *directory* `/my/dir/docker/.` exists, you will get this error (for simple `docker` commands).

The "double" target works because (due to the `{{`) make's trivial parser decides that this command it not "simple enough" to parse directly, and it runs the shell to do it; the shell doesn't get confused by that directory.

You can (1) add the semicolon as above, or (2) figure out why some directory on your `PATH` contains a `docker` subdirectory and remove it.

The next release of GNU make (probably released by the end of the month) will fix this issue (includes a newer version of the gnulib module, with the fix).

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer ! You are right, adding a semicolon makes it work again.
I did have a look closely at my PATH variable, and there was a `::` in the middle (I guess some install script did that). I guess it resolves to the current directory, the project directory, and it indeed contains a `docker` folder :) Removing the duplicated `:`  fixes my problem also !